# IF formula comparing a range

Tags: excel

I need a formula that will take the value in A2 and match it to the range of B.  If there is a match then the result should be the corresponding value in column C.

So in this scenario the result should be Red1:

[image: [Excel color sheet]

Comment: What have you tried? The vlookup formula does this

Comment: Use vlookup() formula

Comment: =VLOOKUP(A2,B2:B5,3,FALSE) but this is the result  #REF!

Answer (score 0):

> `=VLOOKUP(A2,B2:B5,3,FALSE)` but this is the result #REF! – Michael Orther

This is because you supplied **3** for the ***col_index_num*** parameter but your ***table-array*** only has **2** columns. The correct formula would be:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,B2:C5,2,FALSE)
                  ^
```

For more information regarding the `VLOOKUP` function:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1